# Too many daemon threads cause program to fail

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing a program that imitates playing on drums. You sit in front of a camera and hitting a predefined spot causes the program to play some sound. There is more than one drum so I had to do it in multithreading so that person can play i.e. two drums at the same time (like it can happen in real life). My method that plays music looks like that:

```
void playInstrumentSound(InstrumentModel instrument) {

    System.out.println("Playing: " + instrument.getInstrumentName());
    if (instrument.getMedia() != null) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                instrument.setPlaying(true);
                MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(instrument.getMedia());
                player.setVolume(instrument.getVolume());
                player.play();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepLength);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                instrument.setPlaying(false);
            }
        });
        t.start();

    }
}
```

An argument is my model of instrument, here you have a constructor:

```
public InstrumentModel(String instrumentName, float[] coordinates, String pathToSound, float diameter, float addToSpineX,
        float addToSpineY, float addToSpineZ) {
    this.instrumentName = instrumentName;
    this.coordinates = coordinates;
    this.pathToSound = pathToSound;
    this.diameter = diameter;
    this.addToSpineX = addToSpineX;
    this.addToSpineY = addToSpineY;
    this.addToSpineZ = addToSpineZ;

    this.leftHandHighestDistance = 0;
    this.rightHandHighestDistance = 0;
    this.volume = 0;

    this.leftHandMovingCloser = false;
    this.rightHandMovingCloser = false;

    if (this.pathToSound != null) {
        media = new Media(new File(this.pathToSound).toURI().toString());
        setMedia(media);
    }
}
```

The most important thing, in this case, is the path to sound. I have all my sounds in `src/main/resources` and when I create an object I pass something like `src/main/resources/snareDrum.wav`. Basing on this path it creates Media object `(from javafx.scene.media)` so that in the method that plays music we can use it. It works fine but the problem is that after some time I can still see `Playing: ...` when I hit a drum but the program doesn't play sound anymore. It ALWAYS happens after thread that says `Timer-62`. You can see it down here:

[image]

Every time I hit the drum there are 2 threads created- one from JFXMedia and one that says "Timer-xx". Like I said, after the one called "Timer-62" I can`t head sound anymore. Do you have any idea why it happens? Thank you in advance.

Comment: My assumption is that the threads never exit as the `MediaPlayer.play` keeps running in the background. Try manually shutting it down when the play has finished - this might help.

Comment: My first assumption would be that creating a new `MediaPlayer` object in every thread you create is the issue. Have you tried retaining those and checking whether you already have one for the current media and reusing that instead of creating a new one every time?

Comment: @Ben Manually shutting down means? I tried thing like Thread.currentThread().interrupt() but it actually didn`t stop the thread. Don`t have any other ideas since .stop() is deprecated.

Comment: @daniu I can try creating MediaPlayer object in InstrumentModel class immediately after getting path to sound. I think I tried that before and it didn`t work but I`ll try again. Thanks

Comment: @JakubBoruk calling `interrupt` or `stop` (which is deprecated as you rightfully pointed out) does not "stop" the thread, it just sends a signal that the thread can catch to decide it's now going to shut down. You can however try to call `dispose` on the MediaPlayer which frees all resources allocated to it and should open the thread up for a stop.

Comment: @Ben Oh yes it worked! Thank you very much!